# Определить верные координаты при клике SIGMA.JS

Tags: javascript, html, graph

Здравствуй. Мне при клике на граф `sigma.js` нужно добавить точку в место клика. Посмотрел примеры - в них есть какой-то граф, похожий на world of goo. Я не понял из него ничего(
([Сама игра](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/add-node-on-click.html))

Клик я могу отследить:

```
s.bind('clickStage', function(e) {
 ...
}
```

Но если я беру координаты командой `e.data.captor.x`, то получаю неверные координаты. Кружочком выделен основной граф, а остальные точки появились при клике.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто-нибудь шарит, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так ведь есть готовый пример на добавление точки в репозитории проекта - https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/add-node-on-click.html. Смотрите с 400й строки:

```
  dom.addEventListener('click', function(e) { ... });
```